# Simplify LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following query:

```
db.ObjectTags.Where(c => 
    c.TagID == tagID && 
    (!db.DeletedObjects.Any(d=> d.ForObjectTypeID == c.ForObjectTypeID && d.ForObjectID == c.ForObjectID)
    || !db.DeletedObjects.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ForObjectTypeID == c.ForObjectTypeID && d.ForObjectID == c.ForObjectID).Deleted)
)
```

Its goal is to return objects that are not in a deleted state.

The table `DeletedObjects` has two states:

- A record doesn't exist (not deleted)
- A record exists with a `deleted (bool)` value

I need to query where either the record doesn't exist, or if it does the `deleted` value is `false`.

Is there any way to condense that statement eg with `SingleOrDefault()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one `!db.DeletedObjects.Any(...)` and no `SingleOrDefault`

```
var q = db.ObjectTags
   .Where(c=> c.TagID == tagID && !db.DeletedObjects
       .Any(d => d.Deleted && d.ForObjectTypeID == c.ForObjectTypeID && d.ForObjectID == c.ForObjectID));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this linq query

```
db.ObjectTags.Where(c => 
    c.TagID == tagID && 
    (db.DeletedObjects.Any(d=> d.ForObjectTypeID == c.ForObjectTypeID && d.ForObjectID == c.ForObjectID && !c.Deleted))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to left join between `ObjectTags` and `DeletedObjects`. A LINQ query like this:

```
from objectTag in db.ObjectTags
from deletedObject in db.DeletedObjects
    .Where(deletedObject => deletedObject.ForObjectTypeID == objectTag.ForObjectTypeID && deletedObject.ForObjectID == objectTag.ForObjectID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
where deletedObject == null || !deletedObject.Deleted
```